# Symfony passing custom sql parameters in the query

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to pass table name and column name from String to the sql query, but for some reason it doesnt work.

This is an example of what am trying to do from symfony 4.4 documentation :
[image]

This is how I am trying to do it :

```
        $sql = "SELECT
            :col,
            COUNT(*) AS `cnt`
            FROM
            :tab
            GROUP BY
            :col
            ";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([ 'col' => $col , 'tab' => $tab  ]);
    return $stmt->fetchAllAssociative();
```

output :

[image]

meanwhile, it works like this :

```
   $sql = "SELECT
            typeCl,
            COUNT(*) AS `cnt`
            FROM
            client
            GROUP BY
            typeCl
            ";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([ 'col' => $col , 'tab' => $tab  ]);
    return $stmt->fetchAllAssociative();
```

And I still want to make my table and column parametrable .. is there anyway to do that ??
(It is not about my String values I used dump and die and make sure nothign wrong with that)

Answer (score 0):

This is how i made it work :

```
 $sql = "SELECT ".$col.",
            COUNT(*) AS `cnt`
            FROM
            ".$tab."
            GROUP BY
            ".$col."
            ";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([ 'col' => $col , 'tab' => $tab  ]);
    return $stmt->fetchAllAssociative();
```